# How to add multiple columnProperties (fields) to ColumnBuilder?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I am using the below code to display the column properties in jasper report. But I am not able to get the three properties values to single column. Is there any possibility to get three of the properties to display using "," in a single column.

The file contains the below code:

```
DynamicReportBuilder drb = new DynamicReportBuilder();
drb.setTitle("Transaction List Export")
                .setSubtitle("This report was generated at " + new Date())
                .setDetailHeight(15)                    // defines the height for each record of the report
                .setPrintColumnNames(true)
                .setIgnorePagination(true)              // for Excel, we may don't want pagination, just a plain list
                .setMargins(30, 20, 0, 15)              // define the margin space for each side (top, bottom, left and right)
                .setDefaultStyles(titleStyle, subtitleStyle, headerStyle, detailStyle)
                .setColumnsPerPage(1, 10)
                .setUseFullPageWidth(true)              // we tell the report to use the full width of the page. this resizes
                                                        // the columns width proportionally to meat the page width.
                .setAllowDetailSplit(false)
                .setReportName("Client List");
AbstractColumn columnClientLocation = ColumnBuilder.getNew()
                .setColumnProperty("ClientAddress", String.class.getName()+Constants.COMMA)
               .setColumnProperty("ClientCity",String.class.getName()+Constants.COMMA)
                setColumnProperty("ClientPostalCode",String.class.getName())
                .setTitle(messages.getMessage(locale, "group.terminalinfo"))
                .setWidth(80)
                .build();
                width = width + 80;

            /**
             * We add the columns to the report (through the builder) in the
             * order we want them to appear
             */
            if(myContainer.getServiceProvider().equalsIgnoreCase("GOOG")) {
                drb.addColumn(columnTransactionActivity)
                    .addColumn(columnClientLocation);
            }
```

I am unable to get the values of `ClientAddress`,`ClientCity` and `ClientPostalCode` in a single column of jasper report .

I would like to display all these three properties in a single column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **not** use `","` you need to use `CustomExpression` to achieve desired result

**Example**

First add your fields to report, so they can be accessed

```
drb.addField("ClientAddress", String.class.getName());
drb.addField("ClientCity", String.class.getName());
drb.addField("ClientPostalCode", String.class.getName());
```

Then create the `AbstractColumn` with a `CustomExpression`

```
AbstractColumn columnClientLocation = ColumnBuilder.getNew().setCustomExpression(
    return new CustomExpression() {
        public Object evaluate(Map fields, Map variables, Map parameters) {
            String clientAddress = (String) fields.get("ClientAddress");
            String clientCity = (String) fields.get("ClientCity");
            String clientPostalCode = (String) fields.get("ClientPostalCode");
            return clientAddress + ", " + clientCity + ", " + clientPostalCode;
        }

        public String getClassName() {
            return String.class.getName();
        }
    }
).build();
```